# Streaming video in Virtualbox jumpy

Tags: virtualbox, video-streaming

I am trying to get Netflix to work on my Ubuntu netbook.  I know it will not run in Linux so I am trying it in my Win XP virtual machine.  It streams the video but the sound and video are out of sync and the video often freezes and jumps.  I have tried Firefox, Chrome, and even IE.  I am thinking my Atom N455 processor does not work well with virtualization.  All other apps in the VM work fine.  The only issue is streaming [YouTube is jumpy too].
Does anyone know of Virtualbox settings I can try to possibly fix this issue or am I out of luck?

Comment: I do not think that this is a hardware problem. On an old XP laptop (which I am writing from now) I have no problems streaming video. But with a Virtualized XP on Linux Mint (2 core 3.0 GHz CPU and 4GB ram on the host) I have no luck with streaming. I guess it could be something related to the GPU hardware acceleration. I have tried various settings in VBOX and installad guest additions but not find any solution to the problem. A strange thing is that I can look at videos on disk with acceptable quality but most webstreaming services will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you install the virtualbox guest tools. This will surely speed up the virtualization.  Also, try increasing the amount of memory you give the VM. Although I'm assuming you don't have much memory to work with as I'm guessing your Atom N455 is in a Netbook, probably with 1 GB of RAM.  Also, which version of windows are you running.  You might want to try with Windows XP or even earlier (although I don't think anything earlier will run Netflix).  Also, try adjusting the video quality on your movies, you can make it play in SD if you want.  Lastly, you may just not have enough power to do this.  Running in a VM is pretty slow.  It's not really designed to do multimedia things like video and games.  Most applications work alright, but anything with lots of moving stuff on the screen tends to be pretty slow.

Comment: Guest tools are already installed.  I have 1/2 of my RAM devoted to the VM (currently 512MB).  As I stated in the question I am using Windows XP.  I have already tried every setting of video quality on Netflix.  Although the streaming issue is not just with Netflix.

Comment: You will probably experience the same problem with any video, streaming or not.  It seems like quite a lot of work for an Atom processor.  Perhaps you should dual boot for watching movies in Netflix.

Comment: A mpg I copied to the virtual machine's desktop has a sound to video lag. You hear the words about a second before the character mouths the words.  So regular video is not good but it is not as bad as streaming video, since the freezing and jumping is not there.  I do not want to have to reboot just to watch a video.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Ubuntu, but I can tell you that the Atom has difficulty smoothly streaming video in Windows based applications.  After having read up on the Atom and the AMD E-series, the Atom supposedly has a weak GPU, whereas the AMD Bobcat series uses a better GPU than the Atom.  I personally have an Atom and an E-300 machine.  Have not compared the two, but the Atom is a little jumpy when having used it some for HDMI streaming.